# How to use cookies in a project idea?

Tags: security, cookies, project

I have a security project about cookies and I am looking for ideas that can I implement in this field.

Could you please help me to find such idea?

Can I implement a code in java that takes cookies of different sites?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies data is completely in control of the client. Building a validation framework in will be good idea. So that validation logic( security logic) can be separated from the web server.

Comment: Could you explain the idea more, please?